# Junit @value annotated field usage Java

Tags: junit4

what if I need to give two different values for a `@Value` annotated field in a Junit test class. Here I have a boolean field which is `@Value` annotated. so I have to write Junit testcase for scenarios where it can be true as well as false.

I have used `@TestPropertySource(properties = "underwriting.skip=true")`.

for the below field

```
@Value("${underwriting.skip}")
protected Boolean skipUnderwriting;
```

But to test some code, I need to make the value false at some point. Pls suggest.

Comment: What is the use case behind this? What exactly do you want to test? Using `@TestPropertySource(properties = "underwriting.skip=true")` and then testing the value of  `@Value("${underwriting.skip}")` only tests that you are using the correct key `underwriting.skip` in your code.

Comment: The usecase is I need to write testcase for two scenarios. when "underwriting.skip=true" as well as "underwriting.skip=false" in same test class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solution worked for me. I used  ReflectionTestUtils to set value to property field in each test case method.

ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classToTest, "skipUnderwriting", Boolean.TRUE);

Answer (score 0):

You can have different @TestPropertySource annotations for different test classes. Depending on your needs, you can have @TestPropertySource(properties = "underwriting.skip=true") on some tests and @TestPropertySource(properties = "underwriting.skip=false") on others.

(Note: The @TestPropertySource belongs on your test class, not on the actual class.)

Comment: I need to use  "underwriting.skip=true" and "underwriting.skip=false" in same class

Comment: No, you don't - you can always split that class up.